# Coding names with a uniqueid starting form 001 but not exceeding three digits

Tags: python, unique-id

I'm trying to code the names from geo database the total records of names are 957 and i want each name to have the uniqueID and it should not exceed three digits. starting from 001.

The below script started from 101 which now is giving me a problem when i rich to one thousand because it gives me the four digits.

I have been using the below Script to code names but unfortunately i'm now stuck because some ID'S are now having four digits.

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart =101  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return rec
```

Here is the steps to code,

Right-Click on Field Calculator
Set the Parser to Python (Default is usually VB)
Tick Show Codeblock.

Paste the following into the Pre-Logic Script Code

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart =101  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return rec
```

Paste the following code in the smaller box below the Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Click OK.

Comment: Please format the code in the appropriate code blocks that you are using.  There is a selector `{}` on the toolbar that allows you to format code blocks.  Since python is a space sensitive language, doing this helps eliminate the possibility that you're not indenting lines properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [zfill string method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm).  To start at 001 and end at 957, you need to use a text field and do the following in the code block:

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return str(rec).zfill(3)
```

And the expression stays the same:

`autoIncrement()`

Comment: Yes! i did it. Thank you very much, i'm now going to create another field for double so that i can transfer those code to double field since i need the codes in number. I appreciate your help.